# How to save text file contents to Javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm trying to read a text file of over 150,000 lines of text. I want to be able to read the text file and pass it as a parameter for processFileContent.

I tried it this way, but it doesn't work. Also, is there a better way to do this for such big data?

```
function readFile(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (evt) {
    var data = evt.target.result;
};
  reader.readAsText(file);
  return data;
}

document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', readFile, false);

var data = readFile();

function processFileContent(data) {
  var list = data.split('\n');
  ...
```

Comment: _"Also, is there a better way to do this for such big data?"_ Do you mean a "better" way to process the data?

Comment: Yes, a more efficient way perhaps?

Comment: Not certain what occurs within `processFileContent`?, though you should alternatively be able to read `data` in chunks of one to n lines ending in `\n`, instead of calling `.split()` for all of `data` at one call. Not certain how to measure "efficiency"? Compared to what other process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FileReader.onload` event returns results asynchronously. You can use a callback or `Promise` to return `result` of `FileReader` to `processFileContent`. Also `file` at `readFile` would be `event` object, not `.files` property of `event.target`.

```
function readFile(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  if (file) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (evt) {
        resolve(evt.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
      reader.onerror = reject;
    })
    .then(processFileContent)
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err)
    });
  }
}

document.getElementById('file')
.addEventListener('change', readFile, false);

function processFileContent(data) {
  var list = data.split('\n');
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is with scoping.  You declared `data` as a local variable in the `onload` event handler, and tried returning it from the outer function, in which it was `undefined`.  To fix this, you need to move the variable declaration out of the event handler.

You also are expecting a file as an argument to your event handler it seems, however events pass `Event` objects to their event handlers.  To get the file, you need to get `event.target.files[0]`.  This should fix it.

```
function readFile(event) {
    var file = event.target.files[0];  // getting the file Blob
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var data;  // moved declaration
    reader.onload = function (evt) {
        data = evt.target.result;
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
    return data;
}
```