# How to obtain FileReader result?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to read a file from my local machine. I have attached the onFileLoad function to the upload button.

I understand that this is happening asynchronously, but how do I access the contents of the file in another function?

What I mean is, after my file is loaded, I want to be able to store the results (text in the file) into a variable. I'm using React and I want to avoid using global variables.

```
onFileLoad(event){
                 var file = event.target.files[0]; 
            if (file){
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function(e) { 
                    window.contents = e.target.result;

                }
                reader.readAsText(file);      

            }
            else { 
                alert("Failed to load file");
            }
}
```

What I'd ideally like to do is once the file is loaded, do something like

```
  (this.setState({data:myloadedFile})
```

Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying, I've viewed that link but I"m still unsure of how to store the read file in a variable.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553614/how-to-save-text-file-contents-to-javascript-variable

Comment: It helped tremendously. Thank you!